# What is $\int_{0}^{\infty} e ^{x^2} dx$

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion, improper-integrals

I am working in some economic problems and got in stuck with the following integral

What is $\int_{0}^{\infty} e ^{x^2} dx$?

Actully, I remember that we should use Taylor series to calculate it but I do not know more precisely.

Could you please show me in detail?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You should not use a taylor series to evaluate. This will result in serious failure. You can find a derivation in a lot of places, like here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral

Comment: The technique I learned for this particular integral is to let $I=\int_0^\infty e^{-x^2}dx$ and to consider $I^2=(\int_0^\infty e^{-x^2}dx)(\int_0^\infty e^{-y^2}dy)$, having changed the variable for the second occurrence to $y$ to facilitate later steps.  You may now combine these together as a double integral and make the change to polar coordinates and then use $u$-substitution.

Comment: Here are 11 proofs: http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/analysis/gaussianintegral.pdf

Comment: @TranLinh Are you kiding me thats a totaly diffrent question.

Comment: Do you mean $\displaystyle\int_0^\infty e^{x^2}\,\mathrm dx$ or $\displaystyle\int_0^\infty e^{-x^2}\,\mathrm dx$?

Comment: "What is $\int_0^\infty e^{x^2}\,dx$?"  It's larger than any real number.

Comment: With the edit to $\int_0^\infty e^{x^2}dx$ you should be able to very immediately see that this doesn't converge... $e^{x^2}\geq 1$ for all $x\in [0,\infty)$ so $\int_0^\infty e^{x^2}dx \geq \int_0^\infty 1dx \to \infty$

Comment: I think there should be a minus sign with $x^2$

Comment: @FrankMoses why?

Comment: There was originally a minus sign in the post., and the question with the minus sign present is an actually interesting question... one which has been solved many times and several links above already point to a dozen different solutions.  The question with the minus sign is also highly important and relevant to mathematical culture and applications today.  The question *without* the minus sign however is trivial, has no useful applications, and should be obvious without any special tricks that are required for the other more interesting problem.

Comment: @an4s I think otherwise it does not converge.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

\begin{align}
& \int_0^\infty e^{x^2} \, dx \\[10pt]
\ge {} & \int_0^\infty 1 \, dx \text{ because } e^{x^2}>1 \text{ when } x^2>0 \\[10pt]
= {} & +\infty
\end{align}

Answer (score 7):

> $$\int_0^\infty e^{x^2}\,dx > \int_0^\infty x^2 \,dx = \left. \frac{1}{3}x^3 \right|_0^\infty = \infty$$

Unless you meant $\int_0^\infty e^{-x^2}\,dx$ but this is  a rather famous integral!

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Consider $I := \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-x^2}dx$. Then notice $I^2 =\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-x^2}dx\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-y^2}dy $.

Now convert the above expression into polar coordinates and solve for $I^2$. Then take the square root of $I$, then divide $I$ by 2 to obtain the desired solution (notice we can divide by 2 since our $e^{-x^2}$ is even, so $ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-x^2}dx = 2 \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-x^2}dx$

Edit: for the explicit details: $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-x^2}dx\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-y^2}dy  $= $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-(y^2+x^2)}dy $. =  $\int_{\theta=0}^{2 \pi} d\theta\int_{r=0}^{\infty} re^{-r^2}dr$

Incase you mean $\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{x^2}$, it is defined to be $\lim_{a \rightarrow \infty} \int_0^a e^{x^2} dx$. In particular, this integral is $\infty$. To see this notice that $e^{x^2} - x^2 \geq 0$ for every $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Hence, we must have $\int_0^a e^{x^2} dx \geq \int_{0}^{a} x^2 dx$. Then as $a \rightarrow \infty$, the integral of $x^2$ goes to infinity, hence this means $\lim_{a \rightarrow \infty} \int_0^a e^{x^2} dx = \infty$ as desired.

Comment: he edited the question now it's $e^{x^2}$

Answer (score 0):

Considering that $$I_p=\int_{0}^{p} e ^{x^2} dx=e^{p^2} F(p)$$ where appears [the Dawson integral](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DawsonsIntegral.html). If you look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dawson_function), you will see that, for large values of $p$,
$$F(p)= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(2k-1)!!}{2^{k+1} p^{2k+1}}
 = \frac{1}{2 p}+\frac{1}{4 p^3}+\frac{3}{8
   p^5}+O\left(\frac{1}{p^7}\right)$$ This gives a quite good approximation of $I_p$ as shown below
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
p & \text{approximation} & \text{exact} \\
 5 & 7.353140320\times 10^9 & 7.354153748\times 10^9 \\
 6 & 3.644670574\times 10^{14} & 3.644831078\times 10^{14} \\
 7 & 1.376717922\times 10^{20} & 1.376741346\times 10^{20} \\
 8 & 3.928126796\times 10^{26} & 3.928156311\times 10^{26} \\
 9 & 8.419813202\times 10^{33} & 8.419844074\times 10^{33} \\
 10 & 1.350879668\times 10^{42} & 1.350882281\times 10^{42} \\
  20 & 1.307005251\times 10^{172} & 1.307005289\times 10^{172} \\
 30 & 1.222148762\times 10^{389} & 1.222148765\times 10^{389} \\
 40 & 9.294304168\times 10^{692} & 9.294304173\times 10^{692} \\
 50 & 5.448684489\times 10^{1083} & 5.448684490\times 10^{1083}
\end{array}
\right)$$ Using the above and series, you could show that
$$\log(I_p)=p ^2+\log\left(\frac 1{2p} \right)+\frac{1}{2 p^2}+\frac{5}{8
   p^4}+\frac{37}{24 p^6}+O\left(\frac{1}{p^8}\right)$$